# Are all kinds of cookie signed and thus cannot be altered or only session cookie in Play?

Tags: security, session, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the documentation it says that Play signs the session cookie so that the client cannot alter the session information. However, it doesn't not mention anything about non-session cookies. So my question is, does Play sign all kinds of cookies or only the one for sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only signs the one for session

check https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L405

the signed field is defaulted to false. On the other side for the session it's defaulted to true:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L582

Comment: The same happens in Java side: `setCookie` will create an unsigned cookie.